# Checking if an instance in Firebase already exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm attempting to check to see if a string input by a user already exists in my database before I write it in.

Here's what I currently have:

> Firebase:
>
> ```
> players
>       id: 
>       playerContent: Firstname Lastname
> ```

```
class PlayerForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
        newPlayerContent: '',
        exists: null
    };

    this.writePlayer = this.writePlayer.bind(this);
    this.checkIfUserExists = this.checkIfUserExists.bind(this);
}


checkIfUserExists(newPlayerContent) {
var playersRef = firebase.database().ref().child('players');

playersRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasChild(newPlayerContent)) {
        this.setState({ exists });
    }
  })
 }

writePlayer(){
    if(this.exists !== null){
    this.props.addPlayer(this.state.newPlayerContent);
    this.setState({
        newPlayerContent: '',
        })
    }
    else{
    console.log("This player already exists.")
    }
}
```

It keeps allowing it in, regardless. I'm a tad unsure of the *checkIfUserExists* function, specifically if I'm accessing my data right in firebase. I'm outputting the content of newPlayerContent to the console and it is in fact what I input, but I'm not sure if the check is doing its job. Does anything stand out here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure about how firebase works but in your `checkIfUserExists` function you have `this.setState({ exists });` but no actual `exists` variable.  So I assume you want to do `this.setState({ exists: true });`

Answer (score 0):

I used *duplicate* instead of exists .. but this code seems to do exactly as I wish. It won't let you add another person to the database if it already sees that player name in the name field (playerContent).

```
var playersRef = firebase.database().ref();
playersRef.child('players').orderByChild("playerContent").equalTo(newPlayerContent).once("value",snapshot => {
    const userData = snapshot.val();
    if (userData){
      console.log("exists!");

      this.state.duplicate = true;

      console.log(this.state.duplicate)
    }
    else{
      console.log("does not exist.")
      this.state.duplicate = false;
      console.log(this.state.duplicate)
    }
});
```

In the writePlayer function:

```
if(this.state.duplicate !== true){
    this.props.addPlayer(this.state.newPlayerContent);
    this.setState({
        newPlayerContent: '',
        })
    }
    else{
    console.log("This player already exists.")
    }
```

Thought, this does throw a warning —

> Do not mutate state directly. Use setState() 
>   react/no-direct-mutation-state